# sql, update using relational database and substring function

Tags: sql

I'm trying to update my user's ssn when their phone number ends with some specific numbers.

```
UPDATE "Profile"
SET "ssn" = '111151'
where SUBSTRING("phoneNumber",12,13) = '00' OR SUBSTRING("phoneNumber",12,13) = '01' OR SUBSTRING("phoneNumber",12,13) = '02'
```

Does calling `SUBSTRING` multiple times have cost? Is it better to make a relational database with a substring column and then update my table using the new column? How can I do that?
if I write my code like below:

```
UPDATE "Profile"
SET "Profile"."ssn" = '22222'
FROM "Profile"
    INNER JOIN (select  SUBSTRING("phoneNumber",12,13) as "phoneSubstring", "id" from "Profile") as "P1" 
    ON "P1"."id" = "Profile"."id"


where "P1"."phoneSubstring" = '02' OR "P1"."phoneSubstring" = '00' OR "P1"."phoneSubstring" = '01';
```

I would give this error:

```
table name "Profile" specified more than once
```

Which way do you think costs less when my database is big?

Comment: You can do SUBSTRING(...) IN (value, value, value...) instead.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Is this a one time deal query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does calling SUBSTRING multiple times have cost?

Probably.  But the SQL optimizer is free to change the code

> Is it better to make a relational database with a substring column and then update my table using the new column?

No!  That would just increase the size of the data and incur overhead for using it.

Instead, use `IN`:

```
where SUBSTRING(phoneNumber, 12, 13) IN ('00', '01', '02')
```

If performance were a concern, you might want to figure out a way to index this column.  That is tricky, but you could try a derived column with an index on that column.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I/O is going to be the main driver in terms of performance: You are in for a full scan of the entire table upon which you will then execute the substring function at a negligible CPU cost on each row. There is no point in going for a sub select. A full table scan will still be executed for the subselect.

Full table scan: means each and every row is read from the underlying database file.